# Как сменить статус заявки по истечении определенного времени?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть заявочная система. При создании заявки в БД записывается статус заявки, время создания и время окончания заявки. Как сделать так, чтобы по наступлении времени окончания заявки, у заявки менялся статус?

Comment: Делаете скрипт, который меняет статус в зависимости от времени. Прикручиваете скрипт к cron

Comment: [CREATE EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html). Скажем, раз в минуту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта на php

**1) Cron раз в минуту**

Запускаем скрипт, который раз в минуту сравнивает время окончания заявки и если больше или равно - меняем

**2) Сравнивать на самой странице**

На самой странице, когда формируется список заявок сделать как-то так:

```
$date_db = // это дата в бд
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // дата, когда выполняется скрипт
```

Ну а после просто if(){}else()

Сравниваем и выводим пользователю